# Minecraft: using entitydata, putting items in a minecart with chest that have nbt data, in this case written books and renamed paper

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I've got a minecart chest named `Command_Cart` and I'm trying to make it so I can reset it with some items.

I put some written books and paper in, and used the command `/entitydata @e[name=Command_Cart] {}` to get its nbt data, which I put in a command. The only thing I changed was the author of the books, which I wanted to be "MeTheCommandCart". However, every time I run the command, it only resets the chest to empty.

The full command is this:

```
entitydata @e[type=chest_minecart,name=Command_Cart] {Items:[0:{Slot:0b,id”minecraft:written_book”,Count:1b,tag:{pages:[0:”{\”text\”:\”/gamemode @p 0\”}”],author:”MeTheCommandCart”,title:”Gamemode 0”,resolved:1b},Damage:0s},1:{Slot:1b,id”minecraft:written_book”,Count:1b,tag:{pages:[0:”{\”text\”:\”/gamemode @p 1\”}”],author:”MeTheCommandCart”,title:”Gamemode 1”,resolved:1b},Damage:0s},2:{Slot:2b,id”minecraft:written_book”,Count:1b,tag:{pages:[0:”{\”text\”:\”/gamemode @p 2\”}”],author:”MeTheCommandCart”,title:”Gamemode 2”,resolved:1b},Damage:0s},3:{Slot:3b,id”minecraft:written_book”,Count:1b,tag:{pages:[0:”{\”text\”:\”/gamemode @p 3\”}”],author:”MeTheCommandCart”,title:”Gamemode 3”,resolved:1b},Damage:0s},4:{Slot:4b,id”minecraft:paper”,Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:”Command goes under here”}},Damage:0s},5:{Slot:12b,id”minecraft:paper”,Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:”Command goes right of here”}},Damage:0s},6:{Slot:14b,id”minecraft:paper”,Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:”Command goes left of here”}},Damage:0s},7:{Slot:22b,id”minecraft:paper”,Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:”Command goes above here”}},Damage:0s}]}
```

This is exactly the Item nbt data it had, so I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: shouldn't it be `id:<item here>` instead of `id”<item here>”`?

Comment: No, that was how it was showing up in the entitydata

Comment: doesn't hurt to try `id:"minecraft:written_book"`

Answer (score 1):

Key names and values **must** be separated with a colon; your `id` tags are missing that colon.

You are also using an invalid quotation symbol `”`, when it needs to be `"` instead.

Fixed command, removing excess keys (list elements do not use keys, despite the output shown).

```
/entitydata @e[type=chest_minecart,name=Command_Cart] {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{pages:["{\"text\":\"/gamemode @p 0\"}"],author:"MeTheCommandCart",title:"Gamemode 0",resolved:1b},Damage:0s},{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{pages:["{\"text\":\"/gamemode @p 1\"}"],author:"MeTheCommandCart",title:"Gamemode 1",resolved:1b},Damage:0s},{Slot:2b,id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{pages:["{\"text\":\"/gamemode @p 2\"}"],author:"MeTheCommandCart",title:"Gamemode 2",resolved:1b},Damage:0s},{Slot:3b,id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{pages:["{\"text\":\"/gamemode @p 3\"}"],author:"MeTheCommandCart",title:"Gamemode 3",resolved:1b},Damage:0s},{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:"Command goes under here"}},Damage:0s},{Slot:12b,id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:"Command goes right of here"}},Damage:0s},{Slot:14b,id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:"Command goes left of here"}},Damage:0s},{Slot:22b,id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{RepairCost:0,display:{Name:"Command goes above here"}},Damage:0s}]}
```